# How do I calculate the probability of choosing K numbers among N chosen from a probability distribution whose sum is greater than S?

Tags: probability

I'm working with datasets which are histograms of numbers.
As an example of one

```
1: 4,989 occurrences
2: 1,156 occurrences
3: 285 occurrences
4: 58 occurrences
5: 9 occurrences
6: 4 occurrences
TOTAL: 6500
```

e.g. What is the probability of picking 8 numbers (1-6) with this probability distribution and having it sum to 33 or more?

On my 1st pick, I may pick a 1 (with probability of 4989/6500). I may then pick a 6 (with 4/6500 chance), then a 4, then a 1, then 2, then a 1. So that would sum to (1+6+4+1+2+1) 14. How often do I sum to 33 or more?

Comment: I find the sum to be $6501$

Comment: You're right. I mistyped one of the occurrences. I won't edit it now because the number is not as important as the formula and there are already a few answers based on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're picking each number independently at random, their sum will have a distribution which is the eightfold convolution of the one given. Note, however, that the sum of the numbers in your table is $6501$, not $6500$.  So if we put
\begin{align}
p_{1i}&=\cases{\frac{4889}{6501}& for $\ i=1$\\
\frac{1156}{6501}& for $\ i=2$\\
\frac{285}{6501}& for $\ i=3$\\
\frac{58}{6501}& for $\ i=4$\\
\frac{9}{6501}& for $\ i=5$\\
\frac{4}{6501}& for $\ i=6$\\}\\
p_{2j}&=\sum_{i=\max(1,6-j)}^{\min(6,j-1)}p_{1(j-i)}p_{1i}\ \ \text{for }\ 2\le j\le12\ ,\\
p_{4j}&=\sum_{i=\max(2,12-j)}^{\min(12,j-1)}p_{2(j-i)}p_{2i}\ \ \text{for }\ 4\le j\le24\ ,\ \text{and}\\
p_{8j}&=\sum_{i=\max(4,24-j)}^{\min(24,j-1)}p_{4(j-i)}p_{4i}\ \ \text{for }\ 8\le j\le48\ ,\\
\end{align}
then the probability that the sum of your eight numbers is at least $\ s\ $ is $\ \sum_\limits{i=s}^{48}p_{8i}\ $. The actual probability for $\ s=33\ $ turns out to be very small—approximately $\ 1.2\times10^{-12}\ $.

**Addendum:** In response to the OP's enquiry below.

An explanation in layman's terms is easier to give by starting with $\ p_{2j}\ $ rather than $\ p_{8j}\ $.  The quantity $\ p_{2j}\ $ is the probability that any given two of the numbers picked sum to $\ j\ $.  To calculate this, you have to sum the probabilities of all the ways this can occur.

If $\ j<2\ $ or $\ j>12\ $ then it is impossible for two of the numbers to sum to $\ j\ $, so $\ p_{2j}=0\ $ in this case.

If $\ j=2\ $, the only way the two numbers can have that sum is for them both to be $1$, which occurs with probability $\ p_{11}p_{11}=\frac{4989}{6501}\cdot\frac{4989}{6501}=\frac{24890121}{42263001}\ $.

If $\ j=3\ $ the only ways the numbers can have that sum is if the first is $2$ and the second is $1$, which has probability $\ p_{12}p_{11}=$$\frac{1156}{6501}\cdot\frac{4989}{6501}=\frac{5767284}{42263001}\ $, or the first is $1$ and the second is $2$, which has the same probability, $\ p_{11}p_{12}\ $.  Thus the total probability that the two numbers sum to $3$ is $\ p_{12}p_{11}+p_{11}p_{12}= \frac{11534568}{42263001}\ $.

The results of continuing this calculation for all values of $\ j\ $ can be tabulated as follows:
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\text{Sum}&\text{Ways to obtain sum}&\text{probability}\\
\hline
2&(1,1)& p_{11}p_{11}= \frac{24890121}{42263001}\\
\hline
3&(2,1);(1,2)& p_{12}p_{11}+p_{11}p_{12}= \frac{11534568}{42263001}\\
\hline
4&(3,1);(2,2);(1,3)& {p_{13}p_{11}+p_{12}p_{12}+ p_{11}p_{13} =\\ \hspace{-1em}\frac{285\cdot 4989 +1156\cdot1156+ 4989\cdot285}{6501\cdot6501}=\frac{4180066}{42263001}}\\
\hline
5&{(4,1);(3,2);(2,3);\\
\hspace{2em}(1,4)}& {p_{14}p_{11}+p_{13}p_{12}+ p_{12}p_{13}+ p_{11}p_{14} =\\
\frac{58\cdot4989+285\cdot1156+1156\cdot285+4989\cdot58}{6501\cdot6501}=\frac{1237644}{42263001}}\\
\hline
6& {(5,1);(4,2);(3,3);\\
\hspace{1em}(2,4);(1,5)}& {p_{15}p_{11}+p_{14}p_{12}+ p_{13}p_{13}+ p_{12}p_{14}+ p_{11}p_{15}=\\
\hspace{1em}\frac{9\cdot4989+58\cdot1156+285\cdot285+1156\cdot58+4989\cdot9}{6501\cdot6501}=\frac{305123}{42263001}}\\
\hline
7& {(6,1);(5,2);(4,3);\\
(3,4);(2,5);(1,6)}& {p_{16}p_{11}+p_{15}p_{12}+ p_{14}p_{13}+ p_{13}p_{14}+ p_{12}p_{15} + p_{11}p_{16}\\ =\frac{4\cdot4989+9\cdot1156+58\cdot285+285\cdot58+1156\cdot9+4989\cdot4}{6501\cdot6501}=\frac{93780}{42263001}}\\
\hline
8&{(6,2);(5,3);(4,4);\\
\hspace{1em}(3,5);(2,6)}& {p_{16}p_{12}+p_{15}p_{13}+ p_{14}p_{14}+ p_{13}p_{15}+ p_{12}p_{16} =\\
\hspace{1em}\frac{4\cdot1156+9\cdot285+58\cdot58+285\cdot9+1156\cdot4}{6501\cdot6501}=\frac{17742}{42263001}}
\\
\hline
9& {(6,3);(5,4);(4,5);\\
\hspace{2em}(3,6)}& {p_{16}p_{13}+p_{15}p_{14}+ p_{14}p_{15}+ p_{13}p_{16} =\\
\hspace{1em}\frac{4\cdot285+9\cdot58+58\cdot9+285\cdot4}{6501\cdot6501}=\frac{3324}{42263001}}\\
\hline
10&(6,4);(5,5);(4,6)& p_{14}p_{16}+ p_{15}p_{15}+ p_{14}p_{16}= \frac{4\cdot58+9\cdot9+58\cdot4}{6501\cdot6501}=\frac{545}{42263001}\\
\hline
11& (6,5);(5,6)& p_{16}p_{15}+ p_{15}p_{16}= \frac{4\cdot9+9\cdot4}{6501\cdot6501}=\frac{72}{42263001}\\
\hline
12&(6,6)&p_{16}p_{16}= \frac{4\cdot4}{6501\cdot6501}=\frac{16}{42263001}\\
\hline
\end{array}
The equation
$$
p_{2j}=\sum_{i=\max(1,6-j)}^{\min(6,j-1)}p_{1(j-i)}p_{1i}\ \ \text{for }\ 2\le j\le12
$$
is really just mathematical shorthand to represent the process of calculating this table.  Once you have the distribution for the sums of two of the numbers, you now repeat the process to get the distribution of the sums of four of the numbers, which is what the equation
$$
p_{4j}=\sum_{i=\max(2,12-j)}^{\min(12,j-1)}p_{2(j-i)}p_{2i}\ \ \text{for }\ 4\le j\le24
$$
represents, and then again to get the distribution of the sum of all eight numbers, represented by the equation
$$
p_{8j}=\sum_{i=\max(4,24-j)}^{\min(24,j-1)}p_{4(j-i)}p_{4i}\ \ \text{for }\ 8\le j\le48\ .
$$
Of course, this is very tedious to do by hand, but it is quite straightforward to write a set of instructions in a programming language for a computer to carry out the calculations.

Comment: This looks like a very elegant formula, but I don't understand it. Can you break down one of them (eg. 8), in layman's terms for me?

Comment: I've added a detailed explanation of what the equation for $\ p_{2j}\ $ means.  I'm not sure whether it could properly be described as being "in layman's terms", but it's probably about as close as I'm able to do within the available space.

Comment: I was hoping for a simple way to solve this on paper lol. But your explanation led me to write a program to enumerate all the combos, and then after accounting for permutations, I got the answer. I think this is the most concise answer so I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

To get an exact answer you can make a spreadsheet with some blank rows above, then numbers from $1$ to $48$ in column A and you numbers in the matching lines of column B.  In C you put the number of ways to sum to each number, so opposite $8$ you would have $1516\cdot 4 + 285 \cdot 9+$three other terms.  If you use relative addressing and the fact that you have zeros above, you can make one formula and copy right and down, then add the results with a sum of $33$ or more.

You can see it will be very rare.  The average number has to be just over $4$ and getting just one is barely over $1\%$ chance.  If you get a number below $4$ you need to compensate by getting a big one, which is even more unlikely.

I find the chance of $33$ or more is about $1.2 \cdot 10^{-12}$

Comment: Can you share your spreadsheet somehow?

Comment: Can you explain why I'm numbering to 48? What's the significance of that number? I'm not sure I understand how you're coming up with the number of ways to sum to 8. Can you break down those numbers for me?

Comment: I don't understand your logic for summing to 8. I assume you meant (1156*4)+(285*9)+... My interpretation is 2 + 6 add to 8 and there are 1156 and 4 occurrences of those, respectively. But I still need to pick 6 more numbers, so don't I need to multiply by the remaining count (6500-1156-4) for that first term?

Comment: The second column gives the number of ways to add to a number with two picks, so we sum the number of ways to pick $2+6. 3+5, 4+4, 5+3, 2+6$.  You do this for each possible total of two picks, $2$ to $12$.  Then in the third column you put the number of ways for the first three numbers to sum to something from $3$ to $18$.  Because you have the second column, it is the same formula because you are adding one pick to the second column.  We continue that until we have all $8$ picks

Comment: Ross Millikan Do you think you could share your spreadsheet?

Comment: I could, but I think it is better for you to create one.  For a simpler case that has all the spreadsheet complexity, compute the chance of each sum of six sided dice when you roll several of them.  Look at my description and think about how to use mixed references (fixed in one direction, relative in the other).

Comment: I'm not very proficient in Excel programming and honestly, I'm still not 100% I understand your explanation. I was just hoping to see an example so I can make sense of it. Thank you for providing the answer though. I was able to write a program and it resulted in the same number. Now that I've verified it I can apply it to the real dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the trials are independent.

Perhaps not the most elegant of solutions, but since your problem seems perfectly adapted to a computer assisted solution:

1. List all non-increasing sequences in $[\![1;6]\!]^8$ which sum to at least 33 (enumerating only non-increasing sequences makes it easy recursively)
2. For each such sequence count the number of distinct permutations and the probability such a sequence occurs (two sequences which are equal up to a permutation will occur with same probability $p_1^{n_1}\cdots p_6^{n_6}$ where $n_i$ is the number of occurrences of $i$): $(n_1!)\cdots (n_6!)$
3. Compute the sum over non-increasing sequences summing to 33 or more of (number of permutations) * (probability)